# Query with a model method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having an issue performing a query for only objects that are active. I do not have an active column in the database, instead, on a model Game, I have the following method:

```
def complete?
  self.winner ? true : false
end
```

That way if a Game has a Winner, `#complete?` will return true. I want to query for all Games that would return false for this method, is there a way to do this with ActiveRecord? Right now in my controller I'm simply calling `@games = Game.all`, and then in my partial rendering games like:

```
<% unless game.complete? %>
yada yada
<% end %>
```

This seems kind of hacky, and would require me to write a different partial if I want to display "completed" games. Anyway, I was wondering if there is a way in the controller to only assign objects that would return true/false from a model method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about a fast and easy class method?

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.completed_games
        games = []
        Game.all.each { |game| games << game if game.complete? }
        return games
    end
end
```

Then call `Game.completed_games`. You can make one for incomplete games too. You can make that method one line too, but I broke it up so you can see exactly what's going on.

Comment: This loads the entire table. Why not use a scope instead?

Comment: @snowangel In this exact instance, yes, you're right. At the time that I wrote this I was still fairly new to Rails and I don't think I really understood scopes yet. However, in a larger sense, if the method in question is more complicated and cannot be written in SQL, then this approach would still work.

Comment: Makes sense and fair enough!

Comment: @snowangel No problem, thanks for noticing that though! Hopefully that comment helps someone else create better code!

Comment: @snowangel i agree with you that above code will load entire table. About your suggestion to use scope, can you elaborate more?. I know what scope is in Rails but don't sure the relation with this topic.

Comment: @AgungSetiawan the answer below does a good job of articulating how to use scopes.

Comment: @snowangel yup, but answer below uses `winner` because it is a property. What if it is not a property, for instance a method like the original question, can we do that without pull all the data first?

Answer (score 7):

Since `winner` is a property of `Game`, why not query on that? You just need this:

```
completed  = Game.where('winner is not null')
incomplete = Game.where('winner is null')
```

You could also make them [scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) if you so desired:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
    scope :finished,   where('winner is not null')
    scope :unfinished, where('winner is     null')
    #...
end
```

and then you could add further filtering or ordering *before* anything comes out of the database.

Let the database do the work, they're good at searching and slinging data around. Any time you're pulling an entire table out of the database for client-side processing you should think again as you're almost certainly making a mistake.

Answer (score 4):

you can do like this

```
    Game.all.select{ |game| game.complete? }
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to return an ActiveRecord_Relation as opposed to an array
Here is a not very efficient solution, but its a start

```
games = Game.all.map { |game| game.id if !game.complete? }

Game.where(id: games)
```

Returns an `ActiveRecord_Relation` of all game objects that are complete