# get all activerecord items by a method value

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, where-clause

I want to find all objects by a model's method.  I don't know ruby that well so I don't know how to word the question better.

say you have a model with a property `'created_at'`
but say in your model_file.rb you created a method

```
def weeks_from_epoch
#### code code code
end
```

I know you can

```
 model.where(:created_at ='some_value')
```

but how do you `model.where(:weeks_from_epoch = 'some_value)`

Comment: can you show us your code in the method? it might work in a scope

Comment: My question is generic.  I want to know how to do a 'where' on Model methods, not model (columns) I'll try to flesh out my example

Comment: take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977613/query-with-a-model-method

Answer (score 0):

You can do this instead (pass argument)

```
def weeks_from_epoch(some_value)
#### code to get collection according to argument
return collection
end
```

and then you can simply just

```
Model.week_form_epoch("some_value")
```